# canvas.getleft for image returns 0 in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I m trying to get the image position in my canvas. But Canvas.GetLeft and Canvas.GetTop always return 0 even though I drag the image across the canvas. Here is the piece of code below.

```
    private void MouseDragElementBehavior_DragFinished(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Canvas Left Position" + Canvas.GetLeft(image1).ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Canvas Top Position" + Canvas.GetTop(image1)).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("Canvas Index" + Canvas.GetZIndex(image1));
    }
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you show the XAML your using?

Comment: <Canvas Margin="12,0,3,-715"
                Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Height="800"
                   Source="37.jpg"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   Width="465"
                   x:Name="image1">
             <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <el:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"
                                                 DragFinished="MouseDragElementBehavior_DragFinished" />
             </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Image>
        </Canvas>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MouseDragElementBehavior uses a MatrixTransformation, not the canvas' top and left properties.

To retrieve the position, you can try using X and Y properties of the MouseDragElementBehavior:

```
    private void MouseDragElementBehavior_DragFinished(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = (MouseDragElementBehavior)sender;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position: " + behavior.X + " / " + behavior.Y);
    }
```

Comment: Incase I save the X,Y coordinates during my application exit. How can use them to position my image to the same coordinate values during app exit. Basically the idea is the image should be retained in the same position for tomnstoning.

Comment: Give a name to your behavior: `<el:MouseDragElementBehavior x:Name="MouseDrag"`. Then you can access it from your code and manually set the position: `this.MouseDrag.X = 200; this.MouseDrag.Y = 200;`

Comment: I'm doing this myself, and i'm perplexed as to why I can't simply bind the behaviors X and Y to Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top? I tried doing this but whatever reason it doesn't write to my binding.