# Drag Drop an Image in a Canvase in WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop

I use the following code to drag-drop an image in WP7 Silverlight:

```
using Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace MapTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var dragObject = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
            dragObject.Attach(TestMapImage);
        }
...
...
```

First of all, I removed all controls in the new page, and added a canvase, put an image in it. Later in the code, I scaled the image to be 4 times larger, so it became larger than the canvase itself.

```
private void changeMapSize(double scale)
{
    TestMapImage.Width = TestMapImage.Width * scale;
    TestMapImage.Height = TestMapImage.Height * scale;
}
```

But when I try to get the location of the image through dragging, I always get the initial value, and that value doesn't change even if the location of the image changes, I use:

```
testTextBox.Text = Canvas.GetLeft(TestMapImage).ToString();
```

for testing.

Any solutions to get the actual location of the image?

Comment: I think that dragging is actually changes `RenderTransform`, not `Canvas` `Top` and `Left` properties

Comment: But if you could please clarify or give me a simple sample..

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232209/canvas-getleft-for-image-returns-0-in-wp7